# get the response array from a JSON object

Tags: typescript

I am being asked to write a typescript rest api that consumes an old soap api from a vendor and returns it for internal use. I have not touched javascript in years, so I figure this is a really simple question but I can not seem to solve it.

I have a JSON string which I then parse with JSON.parse(JSONstring) and I get the following object:

```
{ '$': { TimeStamp: '7/02/2019 11:20AM GMT-07:00',
 version: '1.0',
 WFCVersion: '8.1.3.1531' }, Response: [ { '$': [Object], Schedule: [Array] } ] }
```

To get that result I am doing: `var key1 = JSONbody['Kronos_WFC']` or `JSONbody.Kronos_WFC`. I am able to get the response with `JSONbody.Kronos_WFC.Response` but for the life of me I can not get to the Schedule which is what I need

I tried multiple version of `JSONbody.Kronos_WFC.Response.Schedule` or `JSONbody.Kronos_WFC.Schedule` All I get is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `JSONbody.Kronos_WFC.Response[0].Schedule` The square brackets in the Response indicate a list or array, and `[0]` will get the first object in the array.

Comment: OMg thank you I knew I was just missing something stupid! Sometimes you just get frustrated with simple things

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer. Welcome to stackoverflow :)